# Parameterise Parm File name In Informatatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I want to know how to (or can I) parameterize the parm file name in informatica?

little bit of background. I am building a standard map in informatica. Which business users can call directly after selecting the standard filters they want to apply in the map using a GUI.

The parm file name will be given by business users and all the filters that he/she selected will be in parm. The file will be dropped in the parm folder in informatica server.

This is a good case scenario, when only 1 users is using it at 1 point of time.

Also, I want to find out what should I do when multiple users are working on GUI and generating the parm files and invoking the informatica map. How do I get multiple instences of the same map running at the same time?

I hope I am making sense here....

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `concurrent execution` of the workflow. Read about it and understand how can you implement it.

Once you know how to implement it, use a backend script/code by the gui to assign an `instance name` to each call through GUI. For each `instance name`, you can have an individual parameter file. (I believe that there would be a finite set of combination of variable values in your case). You can use below command to call individual instances, (either through you GUI or by any other backend code.

```
pmcmd %workflow_name% %informatica_folder_name% 
 -paramfile %paramfilepathandname% -rin %instance_name%
```

It might sound a bit confusing, but once you understand how concurrent workflows work, you can build on it based on the above input.

Comment: Hi Utsav, I ran the command you suggested. I am getting below error message. pmcmd wf_m_Standard_Eligibility_Extract VKONDEPU -parmfile /u02/edw/parm/INNOVU_Standard_Eligibility_Extract.parm -rin R1
ERROR: Unknown command [wf_m_Standard_Eligibility_Extract].

Answer (score 0):

It'll be only possible if you call the Informatica from external tool, not the Client tools. One way is described by @Utsav, the other is when you use Informatica WSH to call a Workflow - you can indicate the parameterfile you want to be used with the workflow, as well as desired instance name.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this guide to concurrent workflows May be what you are looking for:
https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/17/301264.aspx